# Maven multi module project showing double SCA count in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, checkstyle, findbugs, pmd

I have a multi module maven project (java) which I have configured in Jenkins. It is configured as:
ProjectA has modules A,B,C
Now the aggregated count that Jenkins displays through the violations plugin (Checkstyle, PMD, FindBugs) is showing double the actual count i.e. ProjectA has count = A+B+C and the aggregated=ProjectA+A+B+C=A+B+C+A+B+C

Please advise how to fix this so that the aggregated count is same as the count of ProjectA